# What is the best way to do Asynchronous Operation to all rows (large number) from a specific database table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to do Asynchronous Operation to all rows from a specific database table. The rows can be 500000 600000 or more than that. My approach was

```js
router.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.findAll({});
  for(let user of users) {
    let x = await user.... // doing some async task here
  }
})
```

May I know is it ok to do like this?

Comment: are you using `mysql` or `mongodb`  (see tags) ? if its `mongodb` why not use `.uodateMany` query method.

Comment: i prefer to split it up a bit, which makes monitoring and canceling a lot easier. without going into detail, I make a `counter=0` variable and `next()` and `done()` functions. in the bottom of next, you say something like `if(userList[counter++]){ setTimeout(next, 10); }else{ done(); }`

Comment: I am not really updating directly. Suppose based on some attribute i need to fetch something then I need (or not) to update row specifically.

Comment: Processing data row by row in a loop is basically the worst you can do, no matter if MySQL or MongoDB. What are the operation you like to do? Typically you can achieve the same with a single `update` (in MongoDB `updateMany`) command.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `for` and `await` in your code causes the asynchronous tasks to be processed consecutively, whereas it might be faster to let them execute in parallel. But that depends on whether the return value `x` of one asynchronous task influences the next (which would make consecutive execution necessary). If not, then

```js
let results = await Promise.all(users.map(user => user.update...));
```

gives you all results with parallel execution.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, it may even be possible to do it all in one task, similar to `.updateMany`. This would be even faster. Please give your requirement in more detail.